# Concatenate two 32bit numbers to get a 64bit result

Tags: c

I need to concatenate two hexadecimal numbers 32 bits each each, to get a final result of 64 bits.
I tried the following code but didn't get a good result:

```
unsigned long a,b;
unsigned long long c;
c = (unsigned long long) (a << 32 | b);
```

Can anybody help me please?
Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more like: c =  (((unsigned long long)a) << 32) | b);

Comment: I'm just guessing, but is it possible that `a` cannot be shifted 32 bits because `a` is still an `unsigned long`? Shouldn't you cast `unsigned long long` on `a` before shifting?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected and actual output for certain numbers? We need to know what is wrong to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 11):

Use proper fixed size types and be careful about type promotion and operator precedence, e.g.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t a, b;
uint64_t c;

c = ((uint64_t)a << 32) | b;
```

Comment: Use of fixed size types is completely unnecessary here: `unsigned long` is guaranteed long enough to hold the 32 bit source operands, and `unsigned long long` is guaranteed long enough to hold the 64 bit result.

Comment: @caf: it might be unnecessary, but it conveys the programmer's intent much better than using naked types

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast `a` to `long long` before shifting it:

```
unsigned long long c = ((unsigned long long)a << 32 | b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest form is:

```
c = a+0ULL<<32|b
```

Answer (score 0):

The third line should be changed to

```
((unsigned long long)a) << 32 | ((unsigned long long) b)
```

What your current code is doing, is taking the 32-bit variable `a` and shifting it 32 bits to the left (making its value 0, because the bottom 32 bits are all empty), then or-ing it with the 32-bit variable `b`.

What the changed version does is to case the 32-bit variable `a` to 64 bits, shift it 32 bits to the left, cast the 32-bit variable `b` to 64 bits, then or the two 64-bit variables together.  The result is naturally 64 bits.

Comment: you should only need to explicitly cast one of the operands into the wider type - the other will get an implicit cast.

Comment: I don't agree that the cast of `b` is excessive. It's not necessary, but it's a clear statement of what you're intending to have happen here.

Answer (score -1):

I would imagine that this would do the trick:

```
typedef unsigned long U64 ; // your unsigned 64-bit int typedef here
typedef unsigned int  U32 ; // your unsigned 32-bit int typedef here

U64 join( U32 a , U32 b )
{
   U64 result = ((U64)a) << 32
              | ((U64)b)
              ;
   return result ;
}
```

I'll leave to you to divine the appropriate typedefs for U64 and U32.

Comment: stdint.h doesn't ship with versions of Visual Studio prior to VS2010, so you can't, on the MS windows platform, depend on it. Ditto for other/older/noncompliant implementation. Since what constitutes a 32- or 64-bit integer type is implementation dependent, why the downvote?